# Bash trouble in for loop variable name

Tags: bash, loops

I want to create a shell script in debian that:

1. creates a directory for each number from 1 to 12 = d1, d2, d3 , ..., d12.
2. creates the same text file inside every directory
3. changes a string inside the text file
4. downloads files using wget

(Create d1; copy links.txt and rename to d1.txt; change every number from 0 to 99 to 1. Then for d2, rename it to d2.txt, change every number to 2 ...the same for the 12).

```
#!/bin/bash
START=1
END=12
for ((i=START; i<=END; i++))
do
    mkdir d'$i'
    cp /home/user/script/links.txt /home/user/script/d'$i'.txt
    grep -rli '([0-99])' /home/user/script/d'$i'.txt | xargs -i@ sed -i 's/[0-99]/'$i'/g' @
    wget -i /home/user/script/d'$i'/d'$i'.txt
done
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: You should *explain what is not working*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes prevent variable substitution in strings. You should use double quotes instead. Also `[0-99]` doesn't do what you think. The character classes only match a single character at a time, so you're only looking for characters 0-9 there. I think this should do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
START=1
END=12
for ((i=START; i<=END; i++))
do
    mkdir d"$i"
    sed -r 's/([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])/'$i'/g' /home/user/script/links.txt > "/home/user/script/d$i/d$i.txt"
    wget -i "/home/user/script/d$i/d$i.txt"
done
```

Comment: I was not using double quotes, and was creating the directory and not using it! Thank you!

Comment: Strange, the [0-99] is working for me for the 0-12 range.

Comment: It will work sort of. It will match anything that has the characters 0 to 9 in it. That could be either 0, 50, 99, or even 9999999.

Comment: I suggest to replace `mkdir d"$i"` by `mkdir "/home/user/script/d$i"`.